# MongoDB - add nested arrays using Java

Tags: java, arrays, mongodb, nested, mongodb-java

I'm trying to add an array of "discountList" inside of an array of "simulatedProducts" using Java to populate a MongoDB collection. However, they are being added separetely, and I'm not sure how I can write this so that discountList is populated inside the simulatedProducts.

Can someone please help me with this?

This is the code (inside a for each):

```
DBCollection collection = database1.getCollection("wallet");

document.put("ID", id);

BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();

collection.insert(document);

DBObject listItem = new BasicDBObject();
BasicDBObject pushOnProduct = new BasicDBObject();
for (Product produto : wallet.getSimulation().getFutureProductList()){
   listItem = new BasicDBObject("simulatedProduct", new BasicDBObject
                               ("name",produto.getName()).append("minimum",produto.getMinumum()).append[...]);

pushOnProduct.put("$push", listItem);
collection.update(document, pushOnProduct,true,true);

for(Discount discount: produto.getDiscountList()){
    listItem = new BasicDBObject("discountList", new BasicDBObject
                ("nameDiscount",discount.getNameDiscount()).append("percentage",discount.getPercentage()));

    pushOnProduct.put("$push", listItem);
    collection.update(document, pushOnProduct,true,true);
 }
```

Returned result that is added on the collection:

```
{
    "simulatedProduct": [{
            "name": "X",
            "minimum": 1000
        }, {
            "name": "Test",
            "minimum": 2380
        }, "discountList": [{
            "nameDiscount": "Tax",
            "percentage": 3
        }, {
            "nameDiscount": "Something",
            "percentage": 3
        }]
    }
}
```

Expected result:

```
{
    "simulatedProduct": [{
            "name": "X",
            "minimum": 1000,
            "discountList": [{
                "nameDiscount": "Tax",
                "percentage": 3
            }, {
                "nameDiscount": "Something",
                "percentage": 3
            }]
        }, {
            "name": "Test",
            "minimum": 2380
        }, "discountList"
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add little bit more code ? What is the value for `document` field ? Why not just do one update ?

Comment: Added more code. I do a second update because I want to push another list into the product of the first list, so I need it to be there before the push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor the code.

The below code will iterate one product at a time, create an update document with setting `name`, `minimum` and push `discountList` and add the update document to the `productList`.

You can run the update query with the `productList` to push the entire `simulatedProduct` array.

Something like

```
 BasicDBList productList = new BasicDBList();
 for (Product produto : wallet.getSimulation().getFutureProductList()) {
    BasicDBList discountList = new BasicDBList();
    for (Discount discount : produto.getDiscountList()) {
       discountList.add(new BasicDBObject("nameDiscount", discount.getNameDiscount()).append("percentage", discount.getPercentage()));
    }
    productList.add(new BasicDBObject("name", produto.getName()).append("minimum", produto.getMinimun()).append("discountList", discountList));
 }
 DBObject update = new BasicDBObject("$push", new BasicDBObject("simulatedProduct", productList));
 collection.update(document, update, true,true);
```

Comment: Looks like it doesn't recognize "$push", it's giving me "Invalid BSON field name $push" at this line:

DBObject update = new BasicDBObject("simulatedProduct", new BasicDBObject("$push", productList));

Comment: Updated to include the document instead of key value pairs and change the order of the key and push modifier.